# Flutter : Could not find the correct Provider<EntryProvider> above this Page Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Getting a error when trying to run, but no specific things what I could fix
Tried to example given by the error, but no luck. The error even says ask help from stackoverflow so here I am after trying to find help from google, but no luck.

Picture of the error

[image]

Why does my Provider break in this case?

Inside my page

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ChangeNotifierProvider<EntryProvider>
      (
      create: (_)=>EntryProvider(),
      child:(MaterialWidget()),
    );
    final entryProvider = Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Journal'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<List<Entry>>(
          stream: entryProvider.entries,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    trailing:
                    Icon(Icons.edit, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                    title: Text(
                      formatDate(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index].date),
                          [MM, ' ', d, ', ', yyyy]),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              EntryScreen(entry: snapshot.data[index])));
                    },
                  );
                });
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EntryScreen()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside my provider

````
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  DateTime _date;
  String _entry;
  String _entryId;
  var uuid = Uuid();

  //Getters
  DateTime get date => _date;
  String get entry => _entry;
  Stream<List<Entry>> get entries => firestoreService.getEntries();

  //Setters
  set changeDate(DateTime date){
    _date = date;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeEntry(String entry){
    _entry = entry;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //Functions
  loadAll(Entry entry){
    if (entry != null){
      _date = DateTime.parse(entry.date);
      _entry =entry.entry;
      _entryId = entry.entryId;
    } else {
      _date = DateTime.now();
      _entry = null;
      _entryId = null;
    }
  }

  saveEntry(){
    if (_entryId == null){
      //Add
      var newEntry = Entry(date: _date.toIso8601String(), entry: _entry, entryId: uuid.v1());
      print(newEntry.entry);
      firestoreService.setEntry(newEntry);
    } else {
      //Edit
      var updatedEntry = Entry(date: _date.toIso8601String(), entry: _entry, entryId: _entryId);
      firestoreService.setEntry(updatedEntry);
    }
  }

  removeEntry(String entryId){
    firestoreService.removeEntry(entryId);
  }

}```
````

````
class EntryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Entry entry;

  EntryScreen({this.entry});

  @override
  _EntryScreenState createState() => _EntryScreenState();
}

class _EntryScreenState extends State<EntryScreen> {

  final entryController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    entryController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    final entryProvider = Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context,listen: false);
    if (widget.entry != null){
      //Edit
      entryController.text = widget.entry.entry;

      entryProvider.loadAll(widget.entry);
    } else {
      //Add
      entryProvider.loadAll(null);
    }
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<EntryProvider>
    (
        create: (_)=>EntryProvider(),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Consumer<EntryProvider>(
            builder: (context, entryProvider, child){
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text(formatDate(entryProvider.date, [MM, ' ', d, ', ', yyyy])),
              actions: [

                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  onPressed: (){
                    _pickDate(context,entryProvider).then((value) {
                      if (value != null){
                        entryProvider.changeDate = value;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                )
                ],),
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Daily Entry', border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      maxLines: 12,
                      minLines: 10,
                      onChanged: (String value) => entryProvider.changeEntry = value,
                      controller: entryController,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      child: Text('Save',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        entryProvider.saveEntry();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                    (widget.entry != null) ? RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text('Delete',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        entryProvider.removeEntry(widget.entry.entryId);
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ): Container(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
            }
          )
        )
    );
  }

   Future<DateTime> _pickDate(BuildContext context, EntryProvider entryProvider) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context, initialDate: entryProvider.date, firstDate: DateTime(2019),
       lastDate: DateTime(2050));
    if (picked != null) return picked;
  }
}```
````

Did the same in my other file, but still getting the same error with that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the ChangeNotifierProvider widget in the parent of your page so it can after get the Provider. Because now it tries to look for your provider and cannot find it in the tree.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<EntryProvider>(
 create: (_) => EntryProvider(),
 child: YourPageWidget(),
)
```

Your example:

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider<EntryProvider>
      (
      create: (_)=>EntryProvider(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Consumer<EntryProvider>(
          builder: (context, entryProvider, child){
            return StreamBuilder<List<Entry>>(
                stream: entryProvider.entries,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          trailing:
                          Icon(Icons.edit, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                          title: Text(
                            formatDate(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index].date),
                                [MM, ' ', d, ', ', yyyy]),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    EntryScreen(entry: snapshot.data[index])));
                          },
                        );
                      });
                });
          },
        ),
      )
    );
```

Comment: How would it look like in this instance?

Comment: I mean you need to create the ChangeNotifierProvider before you create the widget (I mean in the code and not in the directory). So you need to create it in the widget you are calling your page widget, because with provider you first must create the provider and after you can access the values with the Consumer or the Provider.of(context).

Comment: Tried 
ChangeNotifierProvider<EntryProvider>
      (
    create: (_)=>EntryProvider(),
    child:(ExplorePage()),
    );
And still getting the same That directory comment was stupid and deleted as soon as i thought about it, been stuck with this for hours so brain is a bit dead

Comment: Can you update your code with the new changes to see if I can see the error.

Comment: Beautiful, the big error is gone
But now i am getting
Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>. This is likely a mistake and is therefore
unsupported.

If you want to expose a variable that can be anything, consider changing
`dynamic` to `Object` instead.
'package:provider/src/provider.dart':
Failed assertion: line 304 pos 7: 'T != dynamic'

Comment: I have updated again my answer I forgot to add the type in the Consumer with Consumer<EntryProvider>. It should work now

Comment: This error is dealt with, thank you for explaining how it works and showing an example

Comment: You welcome. I'm happy it fixed your error

Comment: I am wondering, how come i come across examples without ChangeNotifierProvider and they work? I have to add it to every place in my code

Comment: hate to bother, but maybe can help with one last thing. I tried all the changes in the other file (posted into question) But still getting the error, what am i missing?

Comment: I see some people fixing this in their main, but my main looks like this, and i am wondering how to put it together

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<NUser>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test projectt',
        ),
        home:Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}*/

Comment: Because it cannot work if it isn't in the widget tree that's why when you use the example in the new example in the main you can call it from everywhere, but if you create a new stateless widget and after you create the instance of the provider and this one calls your page widget it will also work in all of there children (It's because in the context it cannot find the instance of the provider because it's created in the same widget and the context in that moment does not have that new instance you just created in the build).  Sorry for the late response. Hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Easier option, rather than trying to wrap the widgets was to wrap the main, so everything everywhere works

````
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      StreamProvider<NUser>.value(
        value: AuthService().user,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<EntryProvider>(
        create: (context) => EntryProvider(),
      )
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      home:Wrapper(),
    ),
        );```
````